# Why does the break statement not work here?

Tags: python, break

I just wanna preface this by saying that I'm a beginner and I'm sorry if this is a stupid question/obvious mistake.

I'm making a human vs computer tic tac toe game , and the break statement is not breaking the innermost loop.
The problem arises in the very last loop where even if the human wins , the if conditon below it is not executed. It goes on to play the computer's move and THEN declare that the computer has won.

please do inform me if I should change or add something to my question.

Thank You

```
boardkeys={9:'     ',8:'     ',7:'     ',6:'     ',5:'     ',4:'     ',3:'     ',2:'     ',1:'     '}

def wincon():
    if boardkeys[1]==boardkeys[2]==boardkeys[3]!='     ':
        return True
    elif  boardkeys[4]==boardkeys[5]==boardkeys[6]!='     ':
        return True
    elif  boardkeys[7]==boardkeys[8]==boardkeys[9]!='     ':
        return True
    elif  boardkeys[1]==boardkeys[4]==boardkeys[7]!='     ':
        return True
    elif  boardkeys[2]==boardkeys[5]==boardkeys[8]!='     ':
        return True
    elif  boardkeys[3]==boardkeys[6]==boardkeys[9]!='     ':
        return True
    elif  boardkeys[1]==boardkeys[5]==boardkeys[9]!='     ':
        return True
    elif  boardkeys[3]==boardkeys[5]==boardkeys[7]!='     ':
        return True

hsym="  O  "
csym="  X  "

def ai():
    z=random.randrange(1,10)
    while boardkeys[z]!="     ":
        z=random.randrange(1,10)
    boardkeys[z]=csym

def move():
    no=int(input("enter your move human"))
    if boardkeys[no]=="     ":
        boardkeys[no]=hsym
    else:
        print("invalid move")
        move()
                              
for i in range(10):
    count=0
    move()
    count+=1
    printboard()
    if wincon==True:                     ????
        print("Game Over you won")       ????        
        break                            ????
    elif count==9:
        print("TIED")
        break
    else:
        print()
        print("computer's turn")
        ai()
        printboard()
        if wincon()==True:
            print("Game Over computer won")
            break
        elif count==9:
            print("TIED")
            break
```

Comment: `wincon==True` will never be true; `wincon` is a function, not a boolean value.  The *result of calling the function*, in other words `wincon()`, might possibly be `True` (in which case there's no point explicitly comparing it to `True`).

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @jasonharper yes thank you, that was an unfortunate typo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `if wincon==True:` it should be `if wincon()==True:`, you're calling a function, not reading a boolean.

Comment: oh god , ive been beating my head for over an hour due to a typo. thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem, but I now see that @jasonharper was actually faster than me, so you should give credit to him :-) 

However since he didn't post it as an answer, I'll gladly take the karma if you press the checkmark on my answer.